# How can I make an instance variable accessible to public static methods?

Tags: java

Why I can not access my variable `p` in `mull` class's `iterate` method?

```
public class mull {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
        final JPanel p = createAndShowGUI();

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new MyTimerActionListener());

    timer.start();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    timer.stop();

public static void iterate(){

    for (int i  = 0; i < 55; i++){
         // "p cannot be resolved"
         p.moveSquare(i*10, i*10);
         p.setParamsRing(i*5, i*7, 200, 200);
    }
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
....
}
```

Why does Eclipse force me to use this:

```
((MyPanel) p).setParamsRing(i*5, i*7, 200, 200);
```

instead of:

```
p.setParamsRing(i*5, i*7, 200, 200);
```

?

Comment: Because p is of type JPanel which doesn't have any method setParamsRing().

Comment: To answer the question in your title, because it is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Static scopes can only access static variables.
2. You cannot access a local variable declared inside a method from another method unless you pass it as a parameter to the second method or you redeclare it with global visibility.

so what you need is:

```
public class mull {
    private static final JPanel p;

}
```

**Edit**: And to your last question: it's because p is of type JPanel which doesn't have any method setParamsRing(). You probably added that method in class MyPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `p` as a static field to the class:

```
private static JPanel p;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for a static method to see a variable it has to be static or belong to an instance of a class.

Non-static variables belong to individual instances of a class of which you have none as there is no call to `new`.

Static variables belong to the `Class` itself.

You can either make your variable static or create an instance and access it's JPanel like 
    
`mull m =  new mull();` 
    `m.p.moveSquare(...);`

Eclipse forces you to cast, because `p` is declared to be a `JPanel` and thus it does not have the `setParamsRing()` method you probably introduced in your `MyPanel` class.

Answer (score 0):

Static method can access only other static method and class members. So, define your p to be static.

BTW your class does not seem to be compilable.  You have code out of any method:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new MyTimerActionListener());

timer.start();
try {
  Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
timer.stop();
```